# Twilio sdk working in Debug version , but fails in release version. Check logs below

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

[image]

I checked everything regarding multidex.
Help me out!

Comment: did you tries your app making multidex

Comment: Yes i have added library ,
enabled mutidex = true in build.gradle also in application class Multidex.install();

Comment: I'm not an Android developer, but I checked with the team and they suggested you check your proguard configuration. There is an example one on GitHub here: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-chat-demo-android/blob/master/chat-demo-android/proguard-rules.pro

Comment: Yes , I checked with the sample projects and get to know i have to add some line of code in proguard.
Thanks for help.